# CrossGeolocator GetPositionAsync exits loop/method

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, geolocation

I want to keep the phone's location quite often in an App, so I'm using the GetPositionAsync method, and keep calling that. I've written some code, and when I attach that in a simple OnAppearing method everything works fine. If I write it in a method or while loop, when it gets to the GetPositionAsync or some other local database things, I think only awaitable methods, it goes right out of the loop/method. I am using async. Any ideas?

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 20;

var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

location.Latitude = position.Latitude;
location.Longitude = position.Longitude;

await App.LocationDatabase.SaveLocationAsync(location);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Comment: Your question is not clear please be clear

Answer (score 0):

You're not sharing any loop code, so it's hard to reproduce your issue.

Anyway, you shouldn't call `GetPositionAsync` in a loop, use the `StartListeningAsync` method and connect to the `PositionChange` event instead.

```
async Task StartListeningAsync()
{
    if(CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
        return;

    await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10, true);

    CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += PositionChanged;
    CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError += PositionError;
}

private void PositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
{
    //If updating the UI, ensure you invoke on main thread
    var position = e.Position;
    var output = "Full: Lat: " + position.Latitude + " Long: " + position.Longitude;
    output += "\n" + $"Time: {position.Timestamp}";
    output += "\n" + $"Heading: {position.Heading}";
    output += "\n" + $"Speed: {position.Speed}";
    output += "\n" + $"Accuracy: {position.Accuracy}";
    output += "\n" + $"Altitude: {position.Altitude}";
    output += "\n" + $"Altitude Accuracy: {position.AltitudeAccuracy}";
    Debug.WriteLine(output);
} 

private void PositionError(object sender, PositionErrorEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Error);
    //Handle event here for errors
} 

async Task StopListeningAsync()
{
    if(!CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
        return;

    await CrossGeolocator.Current.StopListeningAsync();

    CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged -= PositionChanged;
    CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError -= PositionError;
}
```

https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/LocationChanges.html